# Apache returns 403 forbidden after refreshing a page

Tags: laravel, apache, vue.js, xampp

A college and I have developed a project together. I did the backend (REST API) with Laravel and my college did the frontend with Vue.js, but we are facing issues when integrating both parts as Apache returns a 403 forbidden every time we refresh the page on the browser.

What we did is an `npm run build` for the Vue.js project and then moved the generated files (index.html, js, css, img...) to Laravel's public directory.

We are not sure if the problem is due to apache's configuration or it's a laravel/vue thing.

This is our apache's httpd.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin user@email.com
    DocumentRoot C:\xampp\htdocs\public
    ServerName  xxxxxx.com
    ServerAlias  xxxxxx.com
    ErrorLog "C:/xampp/error.log"
    CustomLog "C:/xampp/access.log" combined
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\public">
        Options -Indexes
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
        AllowOverride All
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        Require all granted
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And here's the contents from .htaccess inside laravel's public folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Base URL redirects to index
    DirectoryIndex index.html

</IfModule>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your API public? Do you send Laravel's CSRF token with your Vue requests?

Comment: What do you mean if it's public? All the endpoints are working fine and we can use the portal we made (except for when we refresh any page). And about the token, I'm not sure if you're asking for this, but every endpoint we have (except for login) is protected with a Bearer token (we use Laravel Passport).